# Is there a way to 'package' up my Visual Studio installation so I can easily deploy it on other machines?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a number of machines running VS, and each has a slightly different config - display styles, installed plugins, source control extensions, project templates, service packs and so on.

Not only is this annoying when moving from machine to machine but also I have no real way of wiping an install and starting again. I know I *could* use a virtual machine but I really don't like the added overhead of VMs. What I'm looking for is a way of rolling up a Visual Studio install, with all the extra plugins into an installable package so I can just define it once and deploy it everywhere. Is this possible?

Comment: While not the solution to your problem, related: http://dotnetsurfers.com/blog/2011/03/14/extensionsync-a-visual-studio-extension-to-synchronize-other-extensions/

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create an "Unattended Install" for Visual Studio and plugins.

HOWTO:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee225237.aspx

Comment: That just looks like a fresh install of VS from a network location - how does that cater for extensions, plugins, configuration?

Comment: Yes it is an install from network location, with two advantages: 1. No use intervention required, that means configuration options etc would be standard across all installs.  2. You can include plugins as part of bundle so that these would be part of initial install.

Comment: Add an export of your settings file from the "known good" VS and an import of that file after the install-with-plugins and I think you have everything you want.